# reactivity in autocomplete component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular15

I need to update the added value in the DOM. I pushing a new element into the array(options). But it's not updating in the DOM.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-filter-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteFilterExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

 ngOnInit() {
  this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map((value) => this._filter(value))
  );
 }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

  return this.options.filter((option) =>
   option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
  );
 }

 addOption() {
  this.options.push('Four');
 }
}
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzbrop?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts,app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html)

[image]

Comment: you can try like that - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzbrop-wqnksm?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts

Comment: Its affecting the search functionality(i,e autocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzbrop-sjpxpr?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.ts) which automatically updates your options when clicking the "add" button.

The approach is that your `filteredOptions$` (per convention, Observables end with a `$`) are based on two Observable streams:

- Once, the search field input
- Second, the options as an Observable stream which gets updated when the button is clicked

Comment: Works fine but autocomplete feature is braking after the push.

Answer (score 0):

`options` is used to filter the user's input, so the user needs to start typing something first to see the new added option in the autocomplete.

What you are missing is to refill the filteredOptions with `options` once the new value `"Four"` has been added.

```js
  addOption() {
    this.options.push('Four');
    this.filteredOptions = of(this.options);
  }
```

Comment: Works fine but autocomplete feature is braking after the push.